# Flash player integration in JWebBrowser

Tags: java, swing, jwebbrowser, djnativeswing

I am using [Eclipse SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and [DJ Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject/) to open youtube using java.

**CODE**:

```
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class YouTubeViewer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeInterface.open();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("YouTube Viewer");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(getBrowserPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        NativeInterface.runEventPump();
        // don't forget to properly close native components
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NativeInterface.close();
            }
        }));
    }

    public static JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
        webBrowser.navigate("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-Cr0EWwaTk");
        return webBrowserPanel;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image: Youtube Viewer]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This code is all Swing, there is no SWT code.

Comment: How do I make this work?

Comment: Did you try javafx webview (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) ?